# Ford KA Car stereo reset after battery removed, requiring security code

Tags: ford, audio, security

I had the battery replaced in my Ford KA (08), and now the radio is requiring a passcode, which I do not know. Is there a way to find out what the passcode is, or bypass it somehow? I have seen this question [Honda Accord radio anti-theft code not working...what am I doing wrong and what should I do?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7750/honda-accord-radio-anti-theft-code-not-working-what-am-i-doing-wrong-and-what) but it seems specific to Honda's and so does not apply to my Ford. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to take the vehicle VIN to a Ford dealership and ask them as they keep all of the codes. As long as you can prove it is your vehicle (registration should work fine) they'll give it to you for free. This is true of about any vehicle manufacturer. There may be a code on the radio itself. Give the dealership a call and ask what information they need, then provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call to dealership and provide them registration no. They will provide you   code.
Some dealships paste code sticker in glove box or  audio guide